# Django and postgres timezone converts to UTC

Tags: django, postgresql, python-datetime, datetimeoffset

In my app users provide their timezone and saved.

So I handle timezone conversion manually

```
    local_time = datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo(self.time_zone))
      #time_zone is "US/Pacific"
```

Yet still when I save into postgres it is converted back to UTC 0.

In the settings:

```
    # TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' #commented out
    USE_L10N = False
    USE_TZ = False
```

That too did not work, so I made a middleware:

```
    # CUSTOM TIME ZONE HANDLER
    class TimezoneMiddleware:
        def __init__(self, get_response):
            self.get_response = get_response

        def __call__(self, request):
            time_zone = "US/Pacific" #will be changed to a fn call
            if time_zone:
                timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(time_zone))
            else:
                timezone.deactivate()
            return self.get_response(request)
```

In settings:

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        ...
        'time_log_app.utils.TimezoneMiddleware',
    ]
```

This is the function that inserts the data:

```
    def insert_data_time_log(user, data):
       #this is the data obj before insertion

    {
    'clock_out': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 21, 8, 16, 30, 420947, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Pacific')), 
    'hourly_rate': 50
    }
        ...
        TimeLog.objects.create(pk=user, **data)
```

The model:

```
    class TimeLog(models.Model):
        clock_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        clock_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        employee_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

That too is not working!!

I'm pretty much out of hope here, what I'm doing wrong??

Or I should use raw sql for this?

Here is the screenshot of postgres
[image]

Comment: you haven't shown any code which interacts with PostgreSQL.  Is this about PostgreSQL at all?  And the python you do show, it is not clear what context it should be in.  "AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'"

Comment: @jjanes. `from datetime import datetime  datetime.now() datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 21, 8, 45, 17, 189704)`

Comment: I just edit in the function that interacts with PostgreSQL

Comment: Except that left out the important parts which are 1) What is `data`? 2) What happens in `...`?

Comment: Add data object too

Comment: To answer this we will need to show an example that: 1) Provides the value for `self.time_zone` and `local_time`. 2) Where `local_time` is inserted/updated in the database? 3) The schema of the table it is being put in? 4) The value in the database table as returned by a `SELECT` in `psql`.

Comment: And nothing works on that data in `...`?

Comment: time_zone, schema, all edited in

Comment: This is the form of data obj just before insertion, nothing else works on it.

Comment: I should have been clearer, what is the schema of the table in Postgres as shown by `psql`? Also what is the value in the table as returned by `psql` as well the value returned by `show timezone` in `psql`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236264/discussion-between-field-boy-and-adrian-klaver).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL always stores timestamptz in UTC, but converts them to your session timezone when it sends them back to you (and when it receives them from you, it interprets them as being in your session timezone if they lack an explicit timezone).  If you want to see them in a different timezone than your session timezone, you can change your session timezone `set timezone='US/Pacific'` or you can convert it using python once it comes back.

If you declare them to be 'timestamp without time zone' in the database, then it will no longer convert them on the way in or out.

Comment: I already converted them. So how do I stop postgres from converting them?

Comment: See my comments in the discussion. The short version, you can't.

Comment: @jjanes please do not recommend `timestamp`, that will result in an un-anchored timestamp that is returned with no offset. If the user changes their `self.time_zone` then the displayed values will be wrong. Or if @FieldBoy attempts to cast them to `timestamptz` they will be rotated to whatever the value of `show time` is. The only way you have a hope of making that work is adding a column that stores the time zone for the `timestamp`. Then you have to be extremely diligent about making sure that stays correct.